# Nextauth session have no user data

Tags: mongodb, next.js, next-auth

When I login, I don't get a user in the session data. I find a user in the db, but I don't get it in the session. If I console log the user in the `authorize` function, I get a user.

```
import User from "@/utils/user-Schema";
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "username", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "password", type: "password" }
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const foundUser = await User.findOne({ username: credentials?.username})

          if(foundUser && foundUser.password === credentials?.password) {
            return foundUser
          }
        }
        catch(e) {
          console.error(e)
        }
        
        return null
      }
    })
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt"
  },
  secret: process.env.SECRET, 
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login"
  }
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

`provider.tsx`:

```
"use client"

import { SessionProvider as NextAuthSessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { ReactNode } from "react";

type SessionProviderProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

export default function SessionProvider({ children }: SessionProviderProps) {
  return (
    <NextAuthSessionProvider>
      {children}
    </NextAuthSessionProvider>
  );
}
```

I have the content in a session provider in the `provider.tsx`

Answer (score 1):

To get the session data, you just need to wrap the component in which you are going to access it. Let's say you have an Avatar component inside Nav component and you need the user's email to show off.

Nav

```
"use client"

import React from "react"
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"

const Nav = () => {
    return (
        <SessionProvider>
            <Avatar />
        </SessionProvider>
    )
}

export default Nav
```

Avatar

```
import React from "react"
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"

const Avatar = () => {
    const { data: session } = useSession()

    const email = session?.user?.email || undefined

    return (
        <>
            <h4>{email?.toString()}</h4>
        </>
    )
}

export default Avatar
```

Do not forget to add your callbacks in your auth.ts file

```
// authOptions
secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
        if (account && user) {
            token.email = user.email
        }

        return token
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
        return {
            ...session,
            user: {
                ...session.user,
                email: token.email as string,
            },
            error: ""
        }
    }
}
```

and add next-auth.d.ts file inside types folder which is at the root level of your project

```
import { DefaultSession } from "next-auth"

declare module "next-auth" {
    interface User {
        email: string
        // you may add other props which you can use in jwt callback
    }

    interface Session {
        user: User & DefaultSession["user"]
        expires: string
        error: string
    }
}
```